# meaning of "taking credit" in this extract

Tags: meaning-in-context

President Trump spoke for less than a minute, calling the 30,000 mark a "sacred number" and **taking credit**, congratulating "all the people within the administration that worked so hard." He closed the event without answering questions.

I looked into a dictionary and found meaning of "take credit for sth": to get good fruits to some outcome(I know it's not exactly correct). but there isn't "for sth" in upper paragraph. so it sounds like for me "Trump had all the credit to himself." but i think "Trump gave credit for  all the people within administration." is more natural in context.

which one is correct? if neither is correct, please teach me!!

Comment: When you *take credit* for something you are saying that you are the one who accomplished that thing. Trump is claiming that he (and his administration) have achieved the thing in question. I don't think I'm making a political or partisan statement in saying that it is pretty standard for President Trump to try to take credit for everything good that happens anywhere.

Comment: thank you for your answer. then, can i think "taking credit" as "achieving something" in that context?

Comment: "Taking credit" doesn't mean "achieving something" in any context, it means claiming to be the one who achieved the thing in question.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence first says that trump spoke. It goes on to list the features of what he said by using the construction:

“He spoke, A and B, and C.”

Where A, B and C are:

- A he called 30 000 a sacred number
- B he took credit
- C he congratulated the administration.

This would have been clearer if the punctuation had been had been:

“He spoke, A, B and C.” Or “He spoke, A, B, and C”.

However, this aspect of the punctuation does not alter the contents of the list.

B is that “he took credit”, implying that he was the cause, source and inspiration of the commendable A, and that he should be acclaimed, praised and lauded for that reason. Sounds normal? At least in C he then went on to give some credit to the administration.